# Sass extra white space when using #{$this}

Tags: css, sass

I have an element like this

```
.block{
    $this: &;

    &__element{
    // styles go here
    }

    &:hover{
        #{$this}__subelement {
        // styles go here
        }
    }
}
```

This is basically so that I can induce changes on the subelement when hovering on the block that contains it (I'm using BEM). But upon compilation Sass adds extra space

```
.block:hover .block__subelement  {
// styles go here
}
```

And renders this style invalid. The only way to circumvent this is by writing

```
.block{
    $this: &;

    &__element{
    // styles go here
    }

    &:hover{
        #{$this}__subelement{ // remove spacing here
        // styles go here
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this happen? Is it because of the loaders I'm using or?

Answer (score 0):

The Sass compiler will always add a space between a parent and child definition unless you specify the location of the parent rule using the ampersand `&`

You just need to add an ampersand at the start of that rule:

```
.block{
    $this: &;

    &__element{
    // styles go here
    }

    &:hover{
        // Add ampersand to reference parent rule here
        &#{$this}__subelement{ // remove spacing here
        // styles go here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was probably not clear enough. I want the space between `.block` and `.block .block__subelement`, the spacing that I am trying to get rid of is the one between `.block__subelement` and `{`

Comment: I though the question was a bit odd. :) White-space between the rule and definition should not affect the rules at all. See [this example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eEqjgm). Is this breaking in the browser display or is BEM not compiling them correctly?

Comment: Odd, because in my project the extra space made the style not work :S Must be some stylelint issue or something of that sort :/ Thanks for the help